# Why did the earth disappear in the final movie?

Tags: sora-no-otoshimono

I've watched the whole movie, but I don't understand that part when the earth slowly disappears. Who destroyed the earth and why? Can someone please explain this to me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The movie doesn't explain it well since it was only a part of what the story is. It was all explained in the manga.

> Sugata Eishirou was forced to use The Rule by a younger him. The Rule (the monument with writings on it that Sugata inspected earlier) granted his wish on what appears as the last writing space available on it. The wish was for the world to disappear.